# What shape is the Dome in the book?

Tags: under-the-dome

The TV show depicts the Dome as being perfectly round/circular when viewed from above but I'm sure in the book, it is portrayed as somehow following the shape of the town limits. That always seemed very arbitrary - how would the perpetrators (deliberately avoiding spoilers) know?

This question: [Do they live under a dome, or inside a sphere?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39537) asks about the 3D shape of the Dome, but doesn't discuss what the basic 2D shape being extruded is.

Comment: As I recall, it was indeed a dome; the idea, I believe, was basically meant to be like an inverted goblet put down over the town. (Think of a kid trapping an anthill with a wine glass.)  I believe they did some digging and found that it also went below the ground, but I don't recall if they confirmed that it was a full sphere. (The end suggests no, with an edge noticed when it lifts.. But that's not conclusive, as the lower section could have dropped thru the earth or some such; clearly the physics are beyond what we understand.  It could be a Forcefield Pokeball, basically :) )

Comment: To be fair, the other question seems to assume that it has to be one or the other, not allowing for an irregular shape. Vote for duplicate or not as you see fit.

Comment: However, that question assumes the cross-section is circular in either case. I'm asking if that is the case.

Comment: It's clearly not a duplicate, as anyone who actually read the two questions can see. I'm asking the question, and I'm _not_ asking about the same issue - as Michael's answer and subsequent comments discuss.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I agree, and have (along with others) reopened your question.

Answer (score 5):

In the book, the dome is explicitly **NOT a dome** at all.  When Barbie manages to talk to his old commanding officer Cox, on the phone, he learns of some of the specifics.

> "We're calling it the Dome," Cox said, "but it's not a 
>   Dome. At least, we don't think it is. We think it's a capsule 
>   whose edges conform exactly to the borders of the town. 
>   And I do mean exactly."
>
> "Do you know how high it goes?"
>
> "It appears to top out at forty-seven thousand and 
>   change. We don't know if the top is flat or rounded. At least 
>   not yet."

They then talk about how deep.

> "As to how deep ... who knows. All we can say now is 
>   more than a hundred feet. That's the current depth of an 
>   excavation we're making on the border between Chester's 
>   Mill and the unincorporated township to the north." ...
>
> We started in a gravel pit that was already 
>   dug down to forty feet or so. I've seen spectrographic 
>   images that blow my mind. Long sheets of metamorphic 
>   rock that have been sheared in two. There's no gap, but 
>   you can see a shift where the northern part of the sheet 
>   dropped a little. We've checked seismographic reports 
>   from the Portland meteorological station, and bingo. There 
>   was a bump at eleven forty-four AM. Two point one on the 
>   Richter. So that's when it happened."

I don't *believe* they ever come to an answer about whether the bottom actually is closed, and one of the reasons for that is that the dome itself seems to be virtually impossible to detect, except for the effect on others:

> "None of this is conclusive, but it's persuasive. Of course 
>   the exploring has just started, but right now it does look as if 
>   the thing is down as well as up. And if it goes up five miles..."
>
> "How do you know that? Radar?"
>
> "Negative, this thing doesn't show on radar. There's no 
>   way of telling it's there until you hit it, or until you're so close 
>   you can't stop. ...."
>
> ... "So how do you know how high it 
>   is? Lasers?"
>
> "No, they also shoot right through. We've been using 
>   missiles with dummy warheads.

Thus to even test whether the bottom was open-ended, they'd have to tunnel down until they no longer found an edge.

Now, you still might think, "Okay, maybe he means it's a roughly circular dome-like shape that contains the city limits in it exactly, like the smallest hemisphere that contains all the marked edges of the town.

The map given in the book could even support this, as it doesn't look like the town is extremely irregular in shape (although the map is frustratingly incomplete, as merely zooms in on a square section of the town... which doesn't include Dinsmore farm, which was under the enclosure and a significant part of the story.  So it neither specifies the exact borders of Chester's Mill, nor does it include the dome itself!)

[image]

(Map retrieved from [the Stephen King wiki](http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/Chester's_Mill,_Maine), but it matches the book except my copy of the book was in black and white)

But no, a few paragraphs later they make it even more explicit that it specifically matches the borders:

> "Any chance it's some sort of natural phenomenon?" 
>   Barbie asked.
>
> "One that conforms exactly to the man-made borders of a 
>   whole town? Every nook and fucking cranny? What do you 
>   think?"

The cover painting, as well as the title, is merely representational.  Presumably "**Under the Solid Enclosure That Exactly Conforms To The Man-Made Borders Of A Town**" wasn't as catchy a book title.

Comment: Now I'm curious what would happen if the town dis-incorporated. And what would happen if it incorporated more territory.

Answer (score 1):

I think the dome in the book is intended to be a typical, smoothly hemispherical dome. I know it's not exactly proof, but here's what the first edition cover looks like:

[image: Under The Dome cover]

When the dome is described as following the town limits, there are two things that might be at play here:

1. The town limits are *roughly* circular. Given that Chester's Mill is a rural town that seems relatively small and separated from other nearby incorporated areas, it's possible that the town limits are more regular than you might expect. It probably has a densely-populated center, with farms clustered around the outside, in such a way that you could draw something vaguely circular around it and call it a town.
2. The dome may follow the town limits in the sense that it stops at the extremities: it may be placed such that it "touches" the town at the two most extreme points.

Comment: That doesn't actually prove it's a dome - only that by the time that happened it was _then_ a dome. But that's not the intent of my question, I'm asking about the 2D shape not the 3D one ;)

Comment: I should know better than to try and add interesting post-scripts to my answers by now.

Comment: to be more explicit about my answer, I believe that your assumption that "following the town limits" means it can't be a regular circle is incorrect, and that it is just a circle.

Comment: I don't have the book to hand but I was sure it described the shape of C.M. in some detail, and that it certainly wasn't round. I think that may be why the question niggled at the back of my mind!

Comment: I don't have it handy either; I always just assumed the dome "went around the edges of town", but not "followed the outline of the town lines". I'll try to find my copy and check.